# Validating result with appium script

Tags: appium

In an android app, I want to open the caluculator app add 2 numbers using appium script.For example

1. click on '4'
2. click on '+'
3. click on '6'
4. click on '='

The result would be 10. Manually when i see i know that the result is correct.

But It should happen automatically, How to validate the result please explain

Comment: Can you provide an example of the code you have and what you tried to retrieve the result please?

Comment: @Test public void f() {

  driver.findElement(By.name("4")).click();

  driver.findElement(By.name("+")).click();

  driver.findElement(By.name("6")).click();

  driver.findElement(By.name("=")).click();
}

Comment: above is the code.....for clicking those numbers

Comment: i want to validate the result

Comment: Get the id or xpath where it is displaying output. for ex if id is "android.result". then your code will be String result=driver.FindElement(By.ID(""android.result"")).gettext(); compare it with expected  result.contentEquals("10");

Answer (score 1):

You have to use one of testing frameworks - e.g. [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/) or JUnit.
And just after performing code get result and compare it with expected result.

```
//TestNG
String expected = "10";
String result = driver.findElement(By.id("id-result")).getText();
Assert.assertEquals(result, expected, "Result is not correct");
```